# Meaning of a sentence with chiastic structure

Tags: meaning, translation, english-comparison

Can you please translate the sentence below:

> non rimpiango le persone che ho perso col tempo, 
>   ma rimpiango il tempo che ho perso con certe persone

Answer (score 8):

I would translate it as:

> I have no regrets about the people whom I've lost over time, but I regret the
>   time I've lost with certain people.